# semodule_package command not found

Tags: security, centos7, selinux

Hello im trying to install MongoDB on CentOS7. It says there to configure SELInux, which i followed. 
On the third step, it says to execute the following;

```
checkmodule -M -m -o mongodb_cgroup_memory.mod mongodb_cgroup_memory.te
semodule_package -o mongodb_cgroup_memory.pp -m mongodb_cgroup_memory.mod
sudo semodule -i mongodb_cgroup_memory.pp
```

On the second command, an error is ouputted;

`[root@localhost ~]# semodule_package -o mongodb_cgroup_memory.pp -m mongodb_cgroup_memory.mod
-bash: semodule_package: command not found`

Now, im still looking for the correct package to install. I have already install `policycoreutils-2.5-33.el7.x86_64` and `checkpolicy-2.5-8.el7.x86_64` Still, `semodule_package` command is not found.

Anyone knows what package to install to have the `semodule_package` command?

Here is my OS information

- CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `yum whatprovides */semodule_package` you would need to install `policycoreutils-python` package.

Comment: sudo yum install policycoreutils-python